# IEEEtran references split into two pages

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran

I'm writing a journal using IEEEtran template. Bibliography is included in a .bib file. An issue happen (but no error reported by Latex) when generating references: references are split into two pages while they can actually fit into one single page:

Note the blank space at the end of 20th reference
[image]

On another page, 21st reference begins
[image]

When I include

> \usepackage{flushend}

Things do not change much, except the references in second page become evenly listed in two columns.

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: you say "note the blank space" but you have clipped the image so we can not tell what space is after the last printed line, (it appears to finish at the same point as ref 10 in the previous column as expected?) and you have given no indication of your source file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ref 10 and ref 20 are at the same level. After this line, there are still large blank space, which could have been filled with references 21-30. It's hard to see from the image though...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the cause of the problem (a stray "\addtolength{\textheight}{-12cm}" instruction) was not mentioned in the posting and was revealed only in a follow-up contribution. As such, this posting is not likely to be relevant to future readers and users of this site.

Comment: It helped me. This instruction is actually in the template, so everyone using it will eventually have this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks, @DavidCarlisle! When I tried to paste some codes, I found the issue: I added

> \addtolength{\textheight}{-12cm}

on the last page before references.
This command truncates the length of the last page, which is the reference page. After removing this line things work well.

Comment: This is why you should always provide an example code in the question that demonstrates the problem.  No one other than you could know about that, People often solve their own problems while trying to make an example.